# Extract parent directory of file, and then the parent directory of that using regex

Tags: regex

Currently, I have the following regex `(.*\\)(.*\\)(.*\\)`, but what I guess I really want is two different regex that extract separate things.

I am essentially trying to extract two folder names from the given path:

`C:\home\username\folder_number_three\images\image.tif`

to

`folder_number_three` and `images`

By using the above expression, I am able to somewhat group this path into what I want, but I think it would just be easier to just extract the two folder names separately with different regex on the same input.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1) ``\\([^\\]+)\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$`` 2) ``\\([^\\]+)\\[^\\]+$`` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBaLc2/1)). However, there are special methods in programming languages to get folders and subfolders.

Comment: It would help if you explain what your environment is, programming language, what are you doing?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, I know it is much easier using Python, but I am using an opensource tool that requires regex input. I would definitely be using Python otherwise.

Comment: Aha, that explains why you need two regexps and not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the 2 strings using 2 capture groups

```
^(?:[^\\]+\\){3}([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^\\]+\\){3}` Repeat 3 times matching any char except `\`, then match the `\`
- `([^\\]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char except `\`
- `\\` Match a `\`
- `([^\\]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except `\`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJW967/1)

If you need 2 patterns, you change the quantifier with a single group.

For [folder_number_three](https://regex101.com/r/fYkwqT/1):

```
^(?:[^\\]+\\){3}([^\\]+)
```

For [images](https://regex101.com/r/PkCdna/1):

```
^(?:[^\\]+\\){4}([^\\]+)
```

Comment: That's right, there is no need to have 2 separate regex when 2 capture groups can do the job

Comment: /mnt/data/public/folder_three/AD/test/image.tif Hello, what would I do extract folder_three, AD, and test as groups from this regex? This is on a linux server where the slash are different.

Comment: @niketp You could add it to the character class dor example https://regex101.com/r/yxHPv1/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sorry, what I meant was that now I have a new directory structure `/mnt/data/public/folder_three/AD/test/image.tif` , and I would like to create similar capture groups above to capture `folder_three`, `AD`, and `test`.

Comment: @niketp You can use `^(?:/[^/]*){3}/([^/]+)` and change the quantifier to 4 and 5 https://regex101.com/r/5L3ilD/1